# scriptlet in javascript if else condition

Tags: javascript, if-statement, gsp

I am trying to run different scriptlets based on javascript conditions like below

```
function myFunction() {
var myValue = document.getElementById('myValue').value;
if (myValue == 'ONE') {
console.log('ONE');
<% System.out.println 'ONE' %>
}
else if (myValue == 'TWO') {
console.log('TWO');
<% System.out.println 'TWO' %>
}
else (myValue == 'THREE') {
console.log('THREE');
<% System.out.println 'THREE' %>
}
}
```

When i call this function, browser console it prints only `ONE` when `myValue` is one  but in intelliJ console it prints `ONE` , `TWO`, and `THREE`, that means all 3 scriptlets are executed where it should execute only one scriptllet for which the condition gets satisfied. Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Remove that Server code and see what happens.

Comment: if i remove the server code it works fine but my question is using scriptlets with in the javascript if else condition, how to achieve it. Thanks.

Comment: `intelliJ` console probably doesn't recognize JavaScript??? It only recognizes gsp code, in your situation??? Just a guess.